# How to prevent new line in Lambda block statement while calling NormalizeWhitespace method

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have the following piece of code..

```
var tree  = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(
 @"
     Func<string, string> parser = value =>
     {
         return string.Format(""Hello {0}"", value);
     };
");

var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
var result = root.NormalizeWhitespace().GetText().ToString();
```

[image]

While printing the output, NormalizeWhitespace method is pushing semicolon to a new line. Is there anyway we can prevent this?.

Also, Is it possible to move semicolon closer to curly brace.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Because a string literal always captures newlines. Thus, try ending your string literal when it ends, instead of adding a newline to make the parenthesis look nice.

```
var tree  = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(
// The trailing newline might help keep indentation on the first line correct
@"
     Func<string, string> parser = value =>
     {
         return string.Format(""Hello {0}"", value);
     };" // Not this string ends here
);

var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
var result = root.NormalizeWhitespace().GetText().ToString();
```

Less elegant methods include calling `string` methods on the resulting constant, such as the following:

```
var tree  = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(
(@"
     Func<string, string> parser = value =>
     {
         return string.Format(""Hello {0}"", value);
     };
").Trim());    // This could also be .Trim('\n') to only remove the newlines before and after the text

var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
var result = root.NormalizeWhitespace().GetText().ToString();
```

Comment: But why would it move the semicolon after the newline?

Comment: Indeed. The OPs string ended with semicolon and then newline. The outputted final text ends with two newlines and then a semicolon (and possibly another newline though its impossible to tell). I'm not in a position to test the code but if this is a working solution then it surprises me...

Comment: I found that, In Normalize method we can trim newline  like NormalizeWhitespace("    ", true). It works fine now..

Comment: @Deepu, please can you describe your solution to this in more detail? I am having the same issue. Thanks

Comment: @DGreen try this based on my expamle
root.NormalizeWhitespace("    ", true).GetText().ToString();